# debugging with timer/signal always ends up in <timer_settime+16>

Tags: c, timer, gdb, signals

I am using gdb to debug a code that starts a timer. When the timer rings in gdb I always end up at instruction timer_settime+16.
Is this expected behavior?

As an example I slightly modified the code of timer_settime man page. The idea is to pass two arguments: a string of integers and a nsec value. The code launches the timer to ring after nsec, then copies the string. 
I expected that by incrementing the nsec value, gdb stopped at different code lines, to end up inside the copy loop. However it always stops at .

So is this expected behavior?

Is it documented somewhere?

Is there a way to achieve what I expected (i.e.: launch a timer that when ring makes gdb stops where the program was just before (or after) the signal)? (always with nsec granularity).

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>

#define CLOCKID CLOCK_REALTIME
#define SIG SIGUSR1

#define errExit(msg)    do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
                           } while (0)

unsigned char OUT[32];
unsigned char IN[32];

unsigned char ascii2hex(char in){ 

unsigned char out;

    if( ('0' <= in) && (in <= '9') )
        out = in - '0';
    if( ('A' <= in) && (in <= 'F') )
        out = in - 'A' + 10;
    if( ('a' <= in) && (in <= 'f') )
        out = in - 'a' + 10;

    return out;
}

void asciiStr2hex(char * in, unsigned char * out, unsigned int len){

int i = 0;
int j = 0;
for( i = 0; i < len; i+=2){
        out[j++]  = (ascii2hex(in[i  ]) << 4) +  ascii2hex(in[i+1]);
    }
}

void testcode(unsigned char *out, unsigned char *in, unsigned int len){
unsigned int i;
for (i=0;i<len;i++)
    out[i] = in[i];
}

static void print_siginfo(siginfo_t *si)
{
   timer_t *tidp;
   int or;

   tidp = si->si_value.sival_ptr;

   printf("    sival_ptr = %p; ", si->si_value.sival_ptr);
   printf("    *sival_ptr = 0x%lx\n", (long) *tidp);

   or = timer_getoverrun(*tidp);
   if (or == -1)
       errExit("timer_getoverrun");
   else
       printf("    overrun count = %d\n", or);
   }

static void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc)
{
   /* Note: calling printf() from a signal handler is not
      strictly correct, since printf() is not async-signal-safe;
      see signal(7) */

   printf("Caught signal %d\n", sig);
   print_siginfo(si);
   signal(sig, SIG_IGN);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   timer_t timerid;
   struct sigevent sev;
   struct itimerspec its;
   long long freq_nanosecs;
   //sigset_t mask;
   struct sigaction sa;

   if (argc != 3) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <16byte> <time-nanosecs>\n",
               argv[0]);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   asciiStr2hex(argv[1], IN, 32);

   /* Establish handler for timer signal */

   printf("Establishing handler for signal %d\n", SIG);
   sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
   sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
   sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
   if (sigaction(SIG, &sa, NULL) == -1)
       errExit("sigaction");

   /* Block timer signal temporarily */

/*     printf("Blocking signal %d\n", SIG);
       sigemptyset(&mask);
       sigaddset(&mask, SIG);
       if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask, NULL) == -1)
           errExit("sigprocmask");
*/
       /* Create the timer */

   sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
   sev.sigev_signo = SIG;
   sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timerid;
   if (timer_create(CLOCKID, &sev, &timerid) == -1)
       errExit("timer_create");

   printf("timer ID is 0x%lx\n", (long) timerid);

   /* Start the timer */

   freq_nanosecs = atoll(argv[2]);
   its.it_value.tv_sec = freq_nanosecs / 1000000000;
   its.it_value.tv_nsec = freq_nanosecs % 1000000000;
   its.it_interval.tv_sec = its.it_value.tv_sec;
   its.it_interval.tv_nsec = its.it_value.tv_nsec;

   if (timer_settime(timerid, 0, &its, NULL) == -1)
        errExit("timer_settime");

   /* Sleep for a while; meanwhile, the timer may expire
      multiple times */

   printf("Sleeping for %d seconds\n", atoi(argv[1]));

   testcode(OUT, IN, 16);


   /* Unlock the timer signal, so that timer notification
      can be delivered */

  /*   printf("Unblocking signal %d\n", SIG);
       if (sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, NULL) == -1)
           errExit("sigprocmask");
  */
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

When debug into gdb with r 00112233445566778899001122334455 2
I obtain:

```
Program received signal SIGUSR1, User defined signal 1.
0x76fc7c38 in timer_settime () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1
(gdb) x/30i $pc
=> 0x76fc7c38 <timer_settime+16>:   cmn r0, #4096   ; 0x1000
0x76fc7c3c <timer_settime+20>:  mov r4, r0
0x76fc7c40 <timer_settime+24>:  bhi 0x76fc7c4c <timer_settime+36>
0x76fc7c44 <timer_settime+28>:  mov r0, r4
0x76fc7c48 <timer_settime+32>:  pop {r3, r4, r7, pc}
0x76fc7c4c <timer_settime+36>:  bl  0x76fc55b4
0x76fc7c50 <timer_settime+40>:  rsb r3, r4, #0
0x76fc7c54 <timer_settime+44>:  mvn r4, #0
0x76fc7c58 <timer_settime+48>:  str r3, [r0]
0x76fc7c5c <timer_settime+52>:  b   0x76fc7c44 <timer_settime+28>
0x76fc7c60 <timer_settime+56>:  andeq   r0, r0, r2, lsl #2
0x76fc7c64: push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, lr}
0x76fc7c68: sub sp, sp, #600    ; 0x258
0x76fc7c6c: ldr r4, [pc, #340]  ; 0x76fc7dc8
0x76fc7c70: add r1, sp, #512    ; 0x200
0x76fc7c74: add r4, pc, r4
0x76fc7c78: mov r0, r4
0x76fc7c7c: bl  0x76fc56b0
0x76fc7c80: cmp r0, #0
0x76fc7c84: bne 0x76fc7c98
0x76fc7c88: ldr r2, [sp, #512]  ; 0x200
0x76fc7c8c: ldr r3, [pc, #312]  ; 0x76fc7dcc
0x76fc7c90: cmp r2, r3
0x76fc7c94: beq 0x76fc7d94
0x76fc7c98: ldr r5, [pc, #304]  ; 0x76fc7dd0
0x76fc7c9c: ldr r0, [pc, #304]  ; 0x76fc7dd4
0x76fc7ca0: add r5, pc, r5
0x76fc7ca4: add r0, pc, r0
0x76fc7ca8: mov r1, r5
0x76fc7cac: bl  0x76fc5524
```

I am running such code on a raspberry pi, but I'am pretty sure I had the same behavior on another linux machine x86_64.
I have tested with "handle stop SIGUSR1".

Comment: Probably the breakpoint is set at the point where debugging is "safe" to begin. Before that, housekeeping was done (e.g. save registers, set up stack frame).

Comment: What's the instruction before?

Comment: The mechanism used to intercept signals from dbg is quite obscure to me. I thought that gdb can simply intercept all signals before being passed to the child. So I thought there was no real breakpoint, just the child is not allowed to continue as long as gdb retains the signal. 
So you suggest that a breakpoint is set when the signal ring and that stops the execution?

Comment: The whole method doesn't sound right to me. You expect timers with nanosecond precision. And in your debug run you specified 2 nanoseconds if I read things correctly. It will take way more than than to execute the necessary syscall to set the timers, so things might start at that instruction because it's one instruction after the system call. Also, I wouldn't be surprised if the timers won't be able to faster than every 10ms (haven't looked linux timer code for decades, so this could be wrong, but most systems run timers on a 100Hz clock).

Comment: @Art: a few instructions before: 
       0x76fc7c20 <timer_gettime+52>: b 0x76fc7c08
    <timer_gettime+28>0x76fc7c24 <timer_gettime+56>: andeq r0, r0, r3, lsl #2
     0x76fc7c28 <timer_settime>: push {r3, r4, r7, lr}
     0x76fc7c2c <timer_settime+4>: ldr r0, [r0, #4]
     0x76fc7c30 <timer_settime+8>: ldr r7, [pc, #40] ; 0x76fc7c60 <timer_settime+56>
     0x76fc7c34 <timer_settime+12>: svc 0x00000000
     => 0x76fc7c38 <timer_settime+16>: cmn r0, #4096 ; 0x1000
     0x76fc7c3c <timer_settime+20>: mov r4, r0

Comment: So the instruction before is `svc`. I don't know much about ARM, but that smells like a syscall instruction. So like I suspected, you get your signal immediately after returning from the syscall.

Comment: @Art: Yes you are right, by using 2 sec I expected to be quite near the instruction next to the timer initialization, but gdb stops to the same instruction as long as the timer is long enough for the program to be running (trying with 20 nsec provides the same result). Concerning the granularity timers have a nanosecond field, so I guess it can actually work with nano seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that the problem was that I have to `set unwindonsignal off` in gdb to obtain the behavior I expected.